# Python selecting an area on the image with the mouse on PySimpleGui interface

Tags: python, image, user-interface, pysimplegui

I want to select an area on the image using the mouse in an interface written using PySimpleGui. The images I have are contained in sg.Frame and placed in window=sg.Window(). How can this be implemented? It is necessary that a person selects an area on the image using the mouse and the coordinates of the selected area are saved. I know it can be done with Tkinter. But I need it in PySimpleGui, because the interface has been written on it. How can this be implemented? If there is an example, I will be grateful. Or any clue? Here is an example of what I want to get in the end and save the coordinates of this area (this is an example in Tkinter and I need in PySimpleGui):
[Image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tumFV.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `sg.Graph` and draw image on canvas by method `draw_image`.

Set options `drag_submits=True, enable_events=True` in `sg.Graph`, then you can catch click and drag events of mouse which decide the selected area.

Find the example code here [Demo Graph Drag Rectangle](https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/blob/master/DemoPrograms/Demo_Graph_Drag_Rectangle.py)

Note: Remember to update line # 13 to your PNG file.